# Java decimal format symbols are wrong for Liechtenstein

Tags: java

The grouping separator in `java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols` is defined wrong for the country Liechtenstein. It is defined as dot (`.`), but it should be defined as quote (`'`). The Liechtenstein definition should be the same as in Switzerland.
I used the following test with Oracle Java 1.8:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Locale for Liechtenstein: Language DE and country li
    Locale li = new Locale("DE", "li");
    DecimalFormatSymbols li_symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(li);
    System.out.println("LI Grouping symbol is: " + li_symbols.getGroupingSeparator());

    // Locale for Switzerland: Language DE and country ch
    Locale ch = new Locale("DE", "ch");
    DecimalFormatSymbols ch_symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(ch);
    System.out.println("CH Grouping symbol is: " + ch_symbols.getGroupingSeparator());
}
```

It will print out

```
LI Grouping symbol is: .
CH Grouping symbol is: '
```

Is there any way to correct this for the whole java installation?
Changing the locale or decimal symbols at every place in the code, where a decimal format is used to format or parse numbers, is not an option here.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use the Switzerland format ? It does not correct the problem but I don't understand why it wouldn't be ok that way. (I don't mean Switzerland is a much better place than Liechtenstein ... although ... (I'm obviously kidding))

Comment: In Java 9 it looks okay. Is that an alternative?